# How can I add two license agreements to an installer?

Tags: user-interface, wix, installation

I'm new to WiX and I have been working on creating an installer for our application using WiX. I have it correctly installing most of the application and dependencies, but currently it does not have any UI.

I want to add a simple wizard interface and I've read about the Minimal configurations and others, but I have a slightly unusual requirement that I would need two different License style agreements. The first license agreement is a standard license, the second is dealing with government export restrictions.

I've been searching for information on how to set the license agreement in WiX but I'm unsure of how to add two separate screens in which the user must agree to continue? Can you explain how I can add two .RTF files as license agreement wizard pages? Other than that, I do not need a complicated UI, no optional features etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we did was download the [source](http://wixtoolset.org/releases/v3-8-708-0/) then copy the existing license dialog and modified it (we wanted a release notes dialog so we turned off most of the controls).

We then copied and modified WixMinimalUI set to include the dialog. Below is an example for our release notes dialog, you'd want to uncomment the commented out controls and handle their usage. Additionally we created this in it's own project so that other installers could use it, we added a preprocessor variable releaseNotesRtf that can then be set from other projects, this variable is the path to the second rtf document.

```
<Fragment>
<UI>
  <Dialog Id="ReleaseNotesDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlg_Title)">
    <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlgBannerBitmap)" />
    <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
    <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
    <!--<Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="340" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlgDescription)" />-->
    <!--<Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlgTitle)" />-->
    <!--<Control Id="LicenseAcceptedCheckBox" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="207" Width="330" Height="18" CheckBoxValue="1" Property="LicenseAccepted" Text="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlgLicenseAcceptedCheckBox)" />-->
    <Control Id="Print" Type="PushButton" X="112" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIPrint)">
      <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIPrintEula">1</Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
    <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)">
      <Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">!(wix.WixUICostingPopupOptOut) OR CostingComplete = 1</Publish>
      <!--<Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[LicenseAccepted <> "1"]]></Condition>
      <Condition Action="enable">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Condition>-->
    </Control>
    <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
      <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="LicenseText" Type="ScrollableText" X="20" Y="60" Width="330" Height="140" Sunken="yes" TabSkip="no">
      <Text SourceFile="!(wix.WixUIReleaseNotesRtf=$(var.releaseNotesRtf))" />
    </Control>
  </Dialog>
</UI>



  <UI Id="WixUI_MinimalReleaseNotes">
    <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
    <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
    <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

    <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
    <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="Minimal" />

  <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
  <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
  <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
  <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />
  <DialogRef Id="ReleaseNotesDlg"/>

  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">NOT Installed</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="ReleaseNotesDlg">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="ReleaseNotesDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="ReleaseNotesDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="ReleaseNotesDlg" Order="1">NOT Installed OR WixUI_InstallMode = "Change"</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="2">Installed AND NOT PATCH</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="3">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>


  </UI>

  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Thanks I will look into this, can you explain to me how the first dialog in these UI sets gets called? I see the Next buttons calling the new dialog, but what about the first one?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how WiX determines which dialog to call first, as we were just modifying existing code we didn't have to figure that out, but it would be interesting to know.